# Buffer management for SD card in SPI mode

Tags: sd, ram, buffer

I'm looking into implementing storage of large audio files onto an SD card. I'll be using SPI to access the card to avoid any patents by the SD card mafia. I'll be generating a lot of data, about 150 kbyte/s per second and that needs to be read from an ADC and written to a DAC + stored on the card.

I need to use some buffer in external memory (I don't know if I'll have enough RAM on any small MCU, so I'll use something with an external bus). I have no experience doing this, so I'll appreciate any pointers to what strategy to use here.

Comment: Do you plan to use a file system or to store plain data?

Comment: @venny haven't decided yet... I know FAT calls for a lot of resources.

Comment: Is that 150 kilobits or 150 kilobytes? Wouldn't direct write by SPI with DMA suffice?

Comment: @venny that's 150kbytes

Comment: Even at 150 kilobytes, it should be possible to receive ADC data alternately into two 512byte buffers and while one is being filled, the other one is emptied into the card. By the way, which platform are you planning to use?

Comment: @venny - I'm looking at an ARM-CortexM4 right now... it has a built in external RAM interface and if I want to work with buffers I must have it due to the buffer size.

Comment: M4 is a good choice. But buffering more than two 512 byte blocks (that is the card's sector size) seems unnecessary to me. MCUs with SDRAM interface are physically large, and with such large MCU you could as well attach a NAND flash and omit both the SDRAM and SD card.

Comment: @venny The devices I'm looking at all have static memory interfaces (only) so NAND flash would work as well as SRAM for the long and short term storage. The problem I'm having is that the NAND and SRAMs are very very expensive! 2MByte or SRAM are north on $10.

Comment: If you insist on external RAM, STM32F4 and LPC4000 can work with SDRAMs which are virtually free these days (if you desolder them from PC RAM modules).

Comment: Wonder kind explanation on why access the card via SPI has any impact on legal, copyright issue, etc., as quoted from original poster, "SPI to access the card to avoid any patents by the SD Card mafia"

Comment: @EEdeveloper if you make a product using an SD Card and use SD mode you need to pay royalties + membership fees. If you use SPI access you don't pay royalties.

Comment: @user34920 Is the paid method technically superior, in one way or the others? I meant, are these two access methods have same or similar technical performance, like, read/write speed, number/scope of supported 'functions/commands', etc.  Do common SD carda (from typical shops) support both access methods?

Comment: @EEdeveloper yes the full SD bus is FAR superior to SPI in terms of comms speed (which has a massive impact on read speed and some impact on write speed).  The commands supported are pretty much the same. Consumer SD cards support both as a matter of course.  Download the published part of the spec (iirc there's a link on wikipedia) and have a look for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fear the FAT. It makes your job a lot easy.

The only thing you have to do is, before you start reading values at ADC, create the FAT 16 system and a text file. Then once you start reading, simply send the data to that text as simple byte.

I have done similar thing with PIC18F458 at a clock rate of 1Kb per second. Here is a [link](http://www.mikroe.com/download/eng/documents/compilers/mikroc/pro/pic/help/mmc_library.htm) with sample code for same controller with generation of FAT system. This helped me a lot. I hope it would help you too.

This method was best for me as all the values were written in a text file and was easy to convert it in any other format or readable for other software as MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

Consumer-grade SD cards can write at upwards of 2MB/s, so 150kB/s is not a problem.  SPI into SD cards can typically communicate at 25MHz once the card is up and running, so again your throughput requirements (from the card's point of view) are manageable.  Although some SD cards may include RAM buffers for streaming data, at only 150kB/s you wouldn't need to use them.

Cortex-M4's generally have very capable multi-channel DMA, plenty of RAM (100-200kB) and are *fast* - 120 to 200MHz - so you would have all the resources needed to manage all the requirements you've listed: ADC, DAC, SPI/SD and data transfers.  You shouldn't need external RAM.

I should add that many Cortex-M4's have an SDIO peripheral that is (presumably... I don't pretend to know one way or the other) appropriately licensed (cost of licensing included in cost of part?) and is capable of *much* higher communications throughput than SPI (100+MB/s).